# Windows 10 Creators Updates breaks WinForms apps / BSOD

Tags: windows, winforms

When having many layers in a complex WinForms app, Windows 10 Creators crashes. This can easily be reproduced with the code below. When hovering or clicking on the UI on top of >= 40 layers, the system crashes with a BSOD. It should bump into an exception.

Does anyone know a tweak to avoid the full crash?

Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PanelLayers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int maxCount = 45;
            int count = 0;
            this.CreateLayers(this, maxCount, ref count);
        }

        private void CreateLayers(Control BaseControl, int MaxCount, ref int Count)
        {
            if(Count == MaxCount)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = "Click me";
                btn.Location = new Point(8, 8);
                btn.Click += btn_Click;
                BaseControl.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
            else
            {
                Count++;
                Panel pnl = new Panel();
                pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                try
                {
                    BaseControl.Controls.Add(pnl);
                    this.CreateLayers(pnl, MaxCount, ref Count);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception hit at count {0}{1}{2}{1}{3}", Count, Environment.NewLine, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                }
            }
        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello Creators Update!");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of problems with the Creators edition.  But this code is already beyond what I thought was possible.  There is a hard upper limit on how deeply windows can be nested.  Last time I checked, been a while, it was 25 iirc.  BSOD is ugly, it will take a while before Creators stabilizes.  The only possible way you are not going to spend a lot of time on fixing the app is by calling Microsoft Support.

Comment: The problem is obviously  a poor system design. Does it really make a difference if you app crashes with a BSOD or dies in some more graceful way?
 If the point is you found a way to force a BSOD maybe you are posting to the wrong board.

Comment: This has nothing to do with poor design. In complex ERP systems, you may find deeply nested detail levels. There is a Microsoft-defined limit for nested controls, which is 50. When creating the layers, it correctly throws an exception (Error creating Window handle), which is OK. However, once the UI is created, it shouldn't blue screen.

Comment: Apparently this has been reported to Microsoft and they are working on it.  See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-creators-update-bsod-kernel-crash/b8ec01a2-4086-4048-8557-417eb79ce813

Comment: Someone implemented the bug in powershell; it is more easy to test if your computer is affected; just copy-paste it in powershell: 
https://gist.github.com/Nevor/ed3719dad0cf66893e42a9ba024c9174

Beware, if your windows is up-to-date, executing this will crash it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be related to another issue (same?) found on Windows 8/Windows Server 2012. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2870007/-0x0000007f-stop-error-when-you-move-the-mouse-pointer-over-nested-windows-in-windows-8-or-windows-server-2012).

**Update**

Microsoft has provided a fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022716/windows-10-update-kb4022716

Here is its description:

> "Addressed issue (Error 0x7F) with Windows Forms (WinForms) that causes the system to crash after upgrading to the Creators Update."

Answer (score 0):

It seems the same, or a similar problem has appeared again in Win10 build 1803.  The following code triggers a BSOD quickly when playing with moving the mouse over the label/window.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormWithButton
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Control p = this;

            for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++) {
                var p2 = new Panel();
                p.Controls.Add(p2);
                p = p2;
            }

            var b = new Label();
            b.Text = "Hello";
            p.Controls.Add(b);
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```